# Determine image size in JavaScript without `<img>` tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, image

Using JavaScript, how can I determine the size of an image which is not in the document without inserting it in the document?

Could I download the image using AJAX and check its height and width programmatically?

Something like...

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var imageSize = MEGIC_GET_FILE_SIZE_FUNCTION(xmlhttp);
        alert("The image is "+imageSize.width+","+imageSize.height+".");
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","lena.jpg",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I'll be using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), so if it offers functionality to this effect, that suits my needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need ajax.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    alert("The image is " + this.width + "x" + this.height);
}
img.src = "lena.jpg";
```

Comment: +1, with the usual caveats about `onload` for images: In some browsers, the event won't fire when the image is cached. (See "Caveats of the load event when used with images" [here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/))

Answer (score 2):

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = url; 
var height = img.height;
var width = img.width;
```

Comment: This is the right direction, but won't work yet - what if the image hasn't loaded yet when I check for the height / width?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4zX2/1/) for you.  Just use the `Image` object.

Comment: Thanks. I discovered it via @Neal. Very useful, I know.  I'm sure he'll read this comment eventually :]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add it to the document to measure it's size, but you do have to wait for it to at least partially load.  If you need to do it for possibly more than one image at a time, and have it call a callback as soon as the size is available, you can use my imageloader module:

```
var ImageLoader = {
maxChecks: 1000,
list: [],
intervalHandle : null,

loadImage : function (callback, url) {
  var img = new Image ();
  img.src = url;
  if (img.width && img.height) {
    callback (mg.width, img.height, url, 0);
    }
  else {
    var obj = {image: img, url: url, callback: callback, checks: 1};
    var i;
    for (i=0; i < this.list.length; i++)    {
      if (this.list[i] == null)
        break;
      }
    this.list[i] = obj;
    if (!this.intervalHandle)
      this.intervalHandle = setInterval(this.interval, 30);
    }
  },

// called by setInterval  
interval : function () {
  var count = 0;
  var list = ImageLoader.list, item;
  for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    item = list[i];
    if (item != null) {
      if (item.image.width && item.image.height) {
        item.callback (item.image.width, item.image.height, item.url, item.checks);
        ImageLoader.list[i] = null;
        }
      else if (item.checks > ImageLoader.maxChecks) {
        item.callback (0, 0, item.url, item.checks);
        ImageLoader.list[i] = null;
        }
      else {
        count++;
        item.checks++;
        }
      }
    }
  if (count == 0) {
    ImageLoader.list = [];
    clearInterval (ImageLoader.intervalHandle);
    delete ImageLoader.intervalHandle;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Is imageloader ECMA standard or something, or a library? Can you link it?

Comment: @Richard:  no, the entire code is pasted above.  All you have to do is include the code, and then call "ImageLoader.loadImage", providing a callback function and a url of the image.  The nice thing about it is that on a large image, you'll get your callback (with the size) long before it's loaded the whole image.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the source of the image you could use a javascript image object:

```
function MEGIC_GET_FILE_SIZE_FUNCTION(src){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    return {height: img.height, width: img.width};
}
```